# Multiple Gateways on LAN

Tags: networking, firewall, routing, gateway, wide-area-network

This is more a theoretical question.

Let's assume we have a Firewall/DG (with a connected WAN) on LAN IP `192.168.1.1`. All external DNS records for incoming services like OWA, FTP etc. point to this WAN.

Also on the LAN there is another Firewall/DG on `192.168.1.254` which has another WAN connection. This is the Default Gateway for the all the PCs and Servers.

In this situation - will inbound services (let's say RDP to a server, and FTP / HTTPS from the WAN connection on `192.168.1.1` which are NATTed to the servers work, given any return communication from these servers would be from the WAN address on the Firewall `192.168.1.254` (which for the sake of the question, is a totally different WAN IP and range).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unless you also do source NAT in addition to the destination NAT, otherwise return packets won't go out the correct gateway and hence won't be sent to the original client.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with regards to doing Source and Destination NAT in order to achieve this?

Comment: Well, you already write that you use NAT to forward e.g. RDP to the internal server. That's destination NAT (you're changing the destination address). You also need to change the source address so that the connection seems to come from the 192.168.1.1 system, i.e. source NAT.

Comment: Right - otherwise, if the PC making the connection (ie. FTP to the server) saw return traffic coming from a different WAN IP then it connected to, it would drop the t raffic?

Comment: Such traffic would be indistinguishable from all other crap that arrives at any internet-connected device.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?